# What is the simplest optimization algorithm for a multi-parameter closed system?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I'm working on a minimization problem for a wireless communication link. I want to minimize the total bit error rate (BER) of a closed system. My problem is that the signal has multiple (50) subcarriers. Each of them having 2 parameters impacting the bit-error rate. I'm calling them *a* and *b*. Both have a minimum and maximum value, as well as a fixed increment between the potential values.

My question is: **what is the simplest way to minimize the BER in such a scenario ?**

Just a thing i need to point out: With a brute force loop algorithm setting the same *a* and *b* for all subcarriers (*a_u* and *b_u*), I attain a minimum BER that is relatively close to the global minimum. That is to say, when i start optimizing from these newly found *a_u* and *b_u*, the global minimum is always found by increasing *a* for the first few subcarriers and decreasing it for the few last subcarriers. And a similar scenario occur to *b* except that my issue is that i have to optimize both at the same time, which I think is sub-optimal through a brute force loop.

So my thought was to apply an optimization algorithm from this starting point (*a_u* and *b_u*) that make sense in this scenario.